# "Is borg working on the server?"

Tags: borgbackup

I'm trying to setup an automated backup system to backup my Raspberry Pi's data to my Mac Mini. However, calling neither borg init nor borg create from the RPi to the remote Mac Mini repo host seems to reach the borg server running on the Mac Mini.

On the Mac Mini:

```
% sudo borg serve --debug --restrict-to-path /Users/borg/BorgRepos/RetroPie
$LOG DEBUG borg.logger Remote: using builtin fallback logging configuration
$LOG DEBUG borg.archiver Remote: 33 self tests completed in 0.12 seconds
```

On the RPi:

```
$ sudo borg create --debug --stats borg@octolen:/Users/borg/BorgRepos/RetroPie2::Friday2 RetroPie
using builtin fallback logging configuration
35 self tests completed in 0.59 seconds
SSH command line: ['ssh', 'borg@octolen', 'borg', 'serve', '--umask=077', '--debug']
Password:
Remote: zsh:1: command not found: borg
Connection closed by remote host. Is borg working on the server?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/archiver.py", line 4455, in main
exit_code = archiver.run(args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/archiver.py", line 4387, in run
return set_ec(func(args))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/archiver.py", line 134, in wrapper
make_parent_dirs=make_parent_dirs, args=args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/borg/remote.py", line 577, in __init__
raise ConnectionClosedWithHint('Is borg working on the server?') from None
borg.remote.ConnectionClosedWithHint: Connection closed by remote host. Is borg working on the server?
Platform: Linux retropie2 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l
Linux: debian 10.13 
Borg: 1.1.9 Python: CPython 3.7.3
PID: 28539 CWD: /home/pi
sys.argv: ['/usr/bin/borg', 'create', '--debug', '--stats', 'borg@octolen:/Users/borg/BorgRepos/RetroPie2::Friday2', 'RetroPie']
SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND: None
```

I did add /usr/bin/borg to the Mac's firewall's list of applications permitted to allow incoming connections. What am I missing here?

Comment: On the RPi, did you install `borg` very recently, like in the same shell session? If so, you have to tell `zsh` to `rehash`.

Comment: `Remote: zsh:1: command not found: borg` seems to suggest that the `borg` user on your Mac does not have `borg` in its `PATH`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I installed borg recently on the RPi, as in two days ago, but I've since restarted the RPi.

Comment: @fra-san: Borg is installed on the Mac and in its PATH:
```which borg
/usr/local/bin/borg
% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/borg:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

reddit users Moocha and Justin473 [said](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/zubarj/is_borg_working_on_the_server/):

> Does it work if you explicitly provide the full path for the remote borg when creating the archive? I.e., `sudo borg create --debug --stats --remote-path /usr/bin/borg borg@octolen:/Users/borg/BorgRepos/RetroPie2::Friday2 RetroPie` where /usr/bin/borg is the path to the Borg binary as seen on the remote Mac Mini, i.e. as the user named borg on the Mac Mini named octolen would access it.

> it very much sounds like borg isn't in the path when the client connects -- ssh isn't launching an interactive shell and the environment is different to what you'd get with an interactive one.

> ssh will not source user’s profile, so PATH is the system default of something like /usr/bin:/bin. Try passing —remote-path to the client passing the path on the server.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are not answers as the page the link points to may change or disappear, and we can't edit or review the contents of remote pages for correctness. It would be better to summarise the answers given on the remote site and possibly even expand on them with an actual solution that you have verified works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're committed to using `borg` I have nothing to offer. If it's only certain files on your RPi that you wish to back up (as opposed to an "image backup" of the entire SD card), I'd suggest you consider `rsync`.

Your first job will be to understand [what `rsync` does](https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html). At a *top-level*, `rsync` updates files located in a designated ***destination*** to match the files in a designated ***source***. It's a *one-way* operation; i.e. (**source ==> destination**) in that `rsync` will not update files in the ***source*** with files in the ***destination*** - even if they are newer. In fact, it's quite easy to mistakenly "update" a destination file - over-writing a newer file with an older one!

`rsync` offers several options for doing what it does. At the top level I'd say there are three options - *given that* the only two hosts involved are your MacMini, and your RPi. If, for example, your "system" included a NAS, or removable media, the number of options grows. But for a 2-host system, the four options are:

1. RPi as *client*, Mac Mini as *server*
2. Mac Mini as *client*, RPi as *server*
3. and 4. Set up `rsync` as a *service/daemon* - on either the Mac or the RPi.

The [official documentation explains these *Processes and Roles*](https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html) far better than I have. You should read through this, and make these fundamental decisions first. You may wish to consider a number of factors here - factors that will determine how well your implementation meets your needs. For example, if one of your hosts runs 24x7, while the other is intermittently *off-and-on*, that **may** point toward using the 24x7 system toward the server role. This will also depend on the *scheduler* you employ to initiate the backup/synchronization; e.g. `cron`, `systemd` and `launchctl` (Mac only). Yes - this can get a bit complicated, but you're also free to make a choice, and then alter it if you have a better idea.

I'll stop here. You may have more detailed questions about `rsync` if you elect to use it as part of your solution. I haven't mentioned the [image-backup](https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RPi-image-utils) solution here since it's RPi-specific, and [covered on RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/140397/83790), but it *may be* a better tool in your situation. In either case, feel free to ask follow-up specific questions on either once you've chosen your path ahead.